# Как вставить шорткод Contact Form 7 в php-файл?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Для того, чтобы вставить форму нужно использовать:

```
[contact-form-7 id="179" title="Консультация"]
```

Я копирую шорткод этой формы и вставляю на главную в файл `front-page.php`

Форма выводится через контент, но когда я вставляю ее в php-код то не выводится.

Кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой вот **код-решение:**

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="179" title="Консультация"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так форма работать не будет. В php файл надо вставить

```
echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="179" title="Консультация"]');
```

Comment: Работает, 100%) Не возвращает ответ) сейчас попробую

Comment: Совсем не выводит форму

Comment: Вы вот это, что написано - в php код хотя бы вставляете? Или как html пытаетесь?

Comment: <?php do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="179" title="Консультация"]'); ?>

Comment: Решил проблему....нужно было просто добавить echo

Comment: эх, точно, вечно я про echo забываю   ))

Comment: Ребята, вставляю <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="111" title="test"]'); ?>, и ничего. Пусто.

UPD: извините пожалуйста, теги не прописал в самом php файле.